# How to create new channel with discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, channel

I need to create new channel in python. The docs suggested :

```js
await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```

but it is not working, so I tried this :

```
await client.get_guild(guild.id).create_text_channel('test')
```

But this throws another error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_text_channel'
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_text_channel'

Comment: Have you checked that the guild ID is correct? Because if the guild ID doesn't exist, it will return `None`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't really say what's specifically wrong, but I'll provide a couple of examples:

```py
@client.command()
async def makechannel(ctx, *, name):
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name.replace(" ", "-"))
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully created {channel.mention}!")

##############################################################

@client.command()
async def makechannel(ctx, *, name):
    guild = client.get_guild(SOME_GUILD_ID) # you could add the guild id as an arg if you want
                                            # make sure it's an int
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name.replace(" ", "-"))
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully created a text channel in **{guild.name}**!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.create_text_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel)
- [`Client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild) - This will return `None` if no guild with the ID is found